# Constant CENTER couldn't be resolved for rectMode() in Processing

Tags: java, processing

```
public void show(PGraphics pg, float x, float y)
{
    pg.rectMode(CENTER);

}
```

I'm calling `rectMode` with the parameter `CENTER`, which should be a constant of type `int` according to the [docs](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PGraphics.html#rectMode-int-), but `CENTER` couldn't be resolved.

Moreover, `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` of the `processing.core` jar doesn't specify its version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`PGraphics.rectMode(mode)`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PGraphics.html#rectMode-int-) takes a mode as parameter. These modes are defined in the class [`PConstants`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PConstants.html).

To reference the mode [`CENTER`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PConstants.html#CENTER), you should:

- use the code `pg.rectMode(PConstants.CENTER);` and add the following import: `import processing.core.PConstants`;
- keep your method as-is and make the following static import: `import static processing.core.PConstants.CENTER`

> The syntax `rectMode(CENTER)` draws the image from its center point and uses the third and forth parameters of `rect()` to specify the image's width and height.

Comment: Is this the center of the pgraphics or the center of the entire screen?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai That's the center of the pggraphics. I also edited with correct links because it seems the previous ones died